# If value is true in specifically numbered column (eventx), return value in a different column with same x value in name (dayx)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
test1 test2 test3 day1 day2 day3
123   897   264   4    7    8
745   456   098   9    10   5
```

Say I have a vector:

```
vector <- c('123','456')
```

I want to add a new column that queries in test(x) for a value in vector and returns day (x) if the condition is met so that it looks like this:

```
test1 test2 test3 day1 day2 day3 testday
123   897   264   4    7    8     4
745   456   098   9    10   5     10
```

This is what I have so far but obviously it doesn't work... any help would be appreciated :)

```
vector <- c('123','456')
x <- as.character(1:15)
df$test_day <- NA
df$test_day<-   sapply(if (df[eventx],'%in%',vector){
        df[prdayx]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map`.  Subset the dataset with the 'test' columns, and 'day' columns.  With `Map`, check whether the elements in 'test' column are in `vector`.  Based on the logical vector, get the corresponding 'day'.  Here, we assume that there will be only a single match per each row.

```
df1$testday <- unlist(Map(function(x, y) y[x %in% vector],  df1[1:3], df1[4:6]))
df1
#   test1 test2 test3 day1 day2 day3 testday
#1   123   897   264    4    7    8       4
#2   745   456    98    9   10    5      10
```

---

Or another option is to `melt` into 'long' format, get the corresponding 'day' values where 'test' values are `%in%` 'vector' and assign it to a new column

```
library(data.table)
v1 <- melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("^test", "^day"))[value1 %in% vector, value2]
df1[, testday := v1][]
```

Comment: thank you so much! lifesaver again, much appreciated :)